# What are the recommended icon sizes for a Smartwatch app launcher?

Tags: icon, android

I am creating app launcher icon for Android smartwatches.

What sizes should I consider while designing it? I tried searching for a template but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I'm helping improve an open-source app and they're using a 72x72 PNG. Not sure if that's a necessity, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Downloadable UI guides](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#Wear) are available for Android wear from the Android developer site. There's also loads of other information about design principles, structuring and a whole range of other thing in the ["wear" section.](http://developer.android.com/design/wear/index.html)

Apple also provide something similar for the Apple Watch if anyone is looking for that as well, It's called [WatchKit.](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/) The downloadable design resources have all sorts of useful templates but you do need an [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) to get at them.